# Rails: Change an element's class from the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm formatting a menu so that the header is colored differently after you've clicked on it.  I would like to use the same haml template for each view and would like the controller to change the class of the particular html element.  How do I target particular html elements from the controller and add a class to them?

Here's a sample:

The Haml:

```
%tr
  %th
    %a#name-header= link_to "Name", people_path({:sort => 'by_name'})
  %th Date
  %th Description
  %th More Info
```

The Controller:

```
def index
  case params[:sort]
  when "by_name"
    @people = Person.find(:all, :order => "name")
    #How can I change the class of the th element here
  else
    @people = Person.all
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Controller code**

```
def index
  @people, @klass = case params[:sort]
  when "by_name"
     [Person.order(name: :asc), "foo"]
  else
     [Person.all, "bar"]
  end
end
```

**View code**

The css class for the `tr` is `foo` or `bar` based on the `sort` parameter:

```
%tr{class: @klass}
  %th= link_to "Name", people_path(sort: "by_name"), id: "name-header"
  %th Date
  %th Description
  %th More Info
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly change the class of an html element from the controller.

It looks like your class is going to be based on `params[:sort]`. You could check for that in the template to come up with the appropriate css class. It would probably be cleaner to move this into a helper too.

Comment: So my haml has access to the params hash?  Also, what is a partial?

Comment: Yes, it has access to params. I also accidentally wrote partial instead of helper. A partial is just a partial template that you can use to clean up your views. Helpers are located in your app/helpers directory and you can put methods in there to also help clean up your views.